# Getting build errors when using getDeclaredMethod() to invoke a public static method

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following code written, but it keeps throwing

> unreported exception NoSuchMethodException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

and

> unreported exception IllegalAccessException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

```java
@UtilityClass
public class CF {

    private static Integer newFunction() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class CFTest {

    public void testNewFunction() {
        Method method = CF.class.getDeclaredMethod("newFunction");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Integer m1 = (Integer) method.invoke(null);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I need to use `try` and `catch` statements for `NoSuchMethodException` and `IllegalAccessException` in order for this to run normally.

I tried `try` and `catch` with `NoSuchMethodException` and `IllegalAccessException` and it worked, but I was wondering if it really needs it and my code is running per normal or is it just exiting with errors.

Comment: Do you know about _checked_ and _unchecked_ [exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) ?